# Error installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm trying to install many different versions of Ubuntu (12.04/14.04, amd64/x86, server/desktop, etc.) on VirtualBox 14.3.26 on OSX 10.10 and I'm getting the following error:

```
[ 0.000000] Fast TSC calibration failed.]
```

It's the first and only thing to show on the screen before the VM turns off and the VM window disappears (so that the only VirtualBox Manager screen is showing). Strangely, I was able to successfully install once (14.04LTS desktop amd64) before getting all of these failed attempts only minutes later.

What's going on here?

Comment: Restart the VirtualBox kernel modules by issuing 'sudo service vboxdrv restart' in a terminal window and see if it works again.

Comment: That file doesn't exist, I'm using Mac OSX 10.10

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realize that you are using MacOSX. I guess you've already restarted your machine... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many different ISO's, different VM emulated hardware combinations, digging through VirtualBox logs, and addressing the OSX Crash Reporter error logs... I simply installed an older VirtualBox (4.2.x) and restarted my Mac which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is generally a non-fatal message (as was previously described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055593/how-to-solve-fast-tsc-calibration-failed-issue-that-occurs-on-boot-in-virtualbox)).  If your virtual machine is not working, the cause is probably elsewhere.